# target category of extended field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, category-theory

For a topological field theory to be a true “extension” of an Atiyah-Segal theory, the top two levels of its target (*ie* its $(n-1)^{\text{st}}$ loop space) must look like $\text{Vect}$. What other (physical) considerations constrain the choice of target category?  The targets of invertible field theories are (by definition) $\infty$-groupoids and (therefore) can be represented as spectra. What constraints can we impose on target spectra of invertible theories; in particular, on their homotopy groups?

Comment: What is the definition of TFT and the definiton of A-S theory you are using?

Comment: An A-S TFT is a functor from $\text{Bord}_{<n-1,n>}(\mathcal{F})$ to $\text{Vect}$ where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes a set of background fields, *eg* a spin structure. An extended theory is a functor from $\text{Bord}_n(\mathcal{F})$ to a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,n)$-category $\mathcal{C}$ that restricts to an A-S TFT on $(n-1)$- and $n$-manifolds.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Consider adding some references to make the question more accessible to a wider audience.

Comment: Maybe this question would be better suited for mathoverflow.com?